# How to make sure that an element is not covered by another (CSS)?

Tags: html, css

I am new at web developing.
Trying to make site logo look good.
Have two elements, one of them is covered by another so user can't click on first of them.

Help me please making them one above another.
How can I do this stuff using only CSS?

Codepen: https://codepen.io/h071/pen/YOeXaw

This is HTML part:

```
<header>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/a/www/css/style_header.css">

<nav class="container-fluid">
  <a class="logo" href="/a/www/index.php">
    <span>Sitename</span>
  </a>

<p id="reg-auth-title"><a href="/a/include/reg_auth.php">Login|Registration</a></p>
```

And this is CSS:

```
header {
width: 100%;
height: 5em;
position: relative;
}
nav {
width: 100%; 
}

.logo {
display: block;
float: left;
position: absolute;
margin-top: 0.4em;
margin-left: 1em;
}
.logo span {
font-size: 5em;
color: black;
display: inline-block;
/*line-height: 1em;*/
}

#reg-auth-title {
/* width: 20%; */
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
float: left;
}
#reg-auth-title a.top-auth {
font: bold 15px sans-serif;
text-decoration: none;
padding-left: 8px;
padding-right: 8px;
padding-top: 4px;
padding-bottom: 4px;
border: 1px solid red;
border-radius: 5px;  /*other browsers*/
-webkit-border-radius: 5px; /*safari*/
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
cursor: pointer;
color: black;
}

#reg-auth-title a.top-auth:hover {
text-decoration: none;
}

#reg-auth-title a {
font: 15px sans-serif;
font-weight: bold;
text-decoration: none;
color: #58ACFA;
margin-left: 1em;
border-bottom-style: dashed;
border-bottom-color: #58ACFA;
border-bottom-width: 1px;
}
```

Comment: Adjust `z-index` of element. Higher value - more "in front" it is in stack. Just make sure element is non-static positioned

Comment: @Justinas, Couldn't make it right. Can you advice which element and how should be configured using z-index? Or maybe there is another method?

Comment: `#reg-auth-title {z-index: 10; position: relative;}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put your link *above* logo using z-index.

```
#reg-auth-title {
    z-index: 10;
    position: relative; // z-index works only with non-static positioned elements
}
```